# Access transactions

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have two pieces of code in my form constructor. They are equal for a 95%, but I really don't know how to simplify it (VB newbie, came from PHP/C/C++/other non-script languages). Can someone help me with it? How to make a template, or just make a shared class or just some globals to use it? :-o

Pieces are:

```
Private Sub AddOne_Click()
    If isNull(Forms![Constructor]!FieldOne.value) Then
       MsgBox ("Please, fill the field one")
    Else
        Dim workspace As DAO.workspace
        Dim recordset As DAO.recordset
    
        Set workspace = DBEngine.Workspaces(0) 'The current database
    
        workspace.BeginTrans 'Start the transaction buffer

        Set recordset = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("One", dbOpenDynaset)
    
        With recordset
            .AddNew
                !One = Forms![Constructor]!FieldOne.value
            .Update
        End With

        workspace.CommitTrans 'Commit the transaction to dataset

        MsgBox ("New '" + Forms![Constructor]!FieldOne.value + "' added successfully")
        
        Forms![Constructor]!FieldOne.value = Null
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub AddTwo_Click()
    If isNull(Forms![Constructor]!FieldTwo.value) Then
        MsgBox ("Please, fill the field two")
    Else
        Dim workspace As DAO.workspace
        Dim recordset As DAO.recordset

        Set workspace = DBEngine.Workspaces(0) 'The current database

        workspace.BeginTrans 'Start the transaction buffer
    
        Set recordset = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Two", dbOpenDynaset)
    
        With recordset
            .AddNew
                !Two = Forms![Constructor]!FieldTwo.value
            .Update
        End With

        workspace.CommitTrans 'Commit the transaction to dataset
        
        MsgBox ("New '" + Forms![Constructor]!FieldTwo.value + "' added successfully")

        Forms![Constructor]!FieldTwo.value = Null
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you've tagged this 'vbscript' - looks like Access to me (OTOH it's impossible to type a variable in VBScript, and OTH you've used the 'bang' operator). Anyhow:

1) Add a standard module.

2) Add the following helper routine to the module:

```
Function Add(RecordsetName As String, FieldName As String)
    If isNull(Forms![Constructor].Fields(FieldName).value) Then
       MsgBox ("Please, fill " + FieldName)
    Else
        Dim workspace As DAO.workspace
        Dim recordset As DAO.recordset
        Set workspace = DBEngine.Workspaces(0) 'The current database
        workspace.BeginTrans 'Start the transaction buffer
        Set recordset = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(RecordsetName, dbOpenDynaset)
        With recordset
            .AddNew
                .Fields(FieldName).Value = Forms![Constructor].FieldName(FieldName).value
            .Update
        End With
        workspace.CommitTrans 'Commit the transaction to dataset
        MsgBox ("New '" + Forms![Constructor].Fields(FieldName).value + "' added successfully")
        Forms![Constructor].Fields(FieldName).value = Null
    End If
End Sub
```

3) The existing OnClick handlers can now be replaced with

```
=Add("One", "FieldOne")
```

and

```
=Add("Two", "FieldTwo")
```

in the Properties pane and the current method handlers deleted from the form module.